# How can I have gradle multi-project deps that are also standalone libraries?

Tags: gradle, groovy

What I'd ultimately like to achieve is having a top level project that can clone all of my deps, and make them rebuild as necessary. While still allowing them to build by themselves in my CI environment.

my project structure looks like this

```
rpf/
    is/
    sec/
```

`sec` has  a dependency on `is`, `is` does have some deps on some of my other libraries, but currently they are not pulled in to the project for convenience sake in rapid development (though I would like them to be, ultimately they shouldn't be changing frequently which is why I want them separate).

this is a snippet of my dependency resolution in `sec`

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':is')
  implementation 'com.xenoterracide:entity-api'
  implementation 'com.xenoterracide:entity-jpa:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

what I'd like to do, is reference `:is` as `implementation com.xenoterracide:is:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` while retaining the compile project before this one, so that if I change is, I don't have to install the dep before I can use it.

using gradle 4.3.1

**update**

tried this for the composite build, in my `rpf/settings.gradle`

```
include 'is', 'sec'
includeBuild('sec') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.xenoterracide.rpf:is') with project(':is')
    }
}
```

but

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Included build 'sec' collides with subproject of the same name.
```

given the example in the docs for a composite build, I'm uncertain which parameters should be which for my use case

Comment: This question could use an edit both to remove the irrelevant bits and to clarify. e.g. I don't understand _while retaining the compile project before this one_. Just guessing here, but are you familiar with composite builds? Is that what you want, I wonder? - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

Comment: @MichaelEaster actually I haven't read that and I'm not sure which part of this is irrelevant, I've largely been reading https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies which shows use of the `project()` method. these docs "What if one project needs the jar produced by another project in its compile path," blah blah blah, use `project()`.  I'll have  to read the composite stuff tomorrow (I need sleep), it might be a fit, uncertain.

Comment: @MichaelEaster yes that appears to be what I'm looking for, reading it though I'm a bit confused, in my root rpf, how do I say for the `sec` build to substitute the `is` module, the example in the docs is a little confusing because it doesn't clarify which `settings.gradle` (well I think it says it's in the root one, e.g. rpf in my case). It also is only referencing `:` so I'm not clear what the interdependency substitution looks like. Perhaps you could provide a simple example that's a little more detailed than the docs?